# How to regex only special character look like DC3 (ASCII Code)

Tags: regex

Do you know how to regex for find all special character or character look like this?

I need to revolve one catalog but I just use that : `[^\x00-\x7F]`

I can't find `DC3`.

[image]

Do you have an idea? I'm so lost.

Thanks very much for your help. I'm a begginer in regular expression.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with *but I just use that... `[^\x00-\x7F]`*? This excludes `\x13` (hex for dec 19 in ascii table *device control 3*). Try `[^\x20-\x7F]` for matching control characters and extended.

Comment: you may want to use `[[:cntrl:]]`

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/211084/notepad-ctrl-s-does-not-save-instead-inserts-dc3-ctrl-f-inserts-ack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answer, I use notepad++, i try to find in the beginning all character look like : ( é, ç, è à in my file but I just realised in my file catalog, I have another character which cause me problem for my integration Symfony.

I try [^\x20-\x7F] and [[:cntrl:]], it's great, it detected my DC3

Do you know just regex only ASCII control characters?
Look like this :
[DC3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxuDk.jpg)

Comment: [^\x00-\x1F] ?? I try this but it match all character 1 per 1,

Comment: Do you know, how to regex with a borner? x00 to x20 in example

Comment: You mean `[\x00-\x20]` for control characters? Just see the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) hex value (use preceded by `\x`).

Comment: oops, this contains space. it should be `[\x00-\x19]` for the non printables (: you're welcome. you can accept your own answer if problem is solved by ticking mark left of answer if you like.

Comment: ah you are reason, I have the characters "space" in my regex. But I use this now [\x10-\x19] when i use [\x9-\x19] I have space too :/ I think it's HorizontalTab, well have a good day ! you make my day so great haha

Comment: Oh that was wrong too, probably you need `[\x00-\x08\x0e-\x1f]` for also allowing horziontal tab... just check the ascii table :) have a good day too (: